# How do I check if a row with parameters exists and roll back transaction if it does? [RoR 6]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm new to Rails and I'm having a hard time understanding how to do the following:

1. a user creates an entry that has two values "Name" and "Position".
2. I want to check and see if that name + position combo already exists in the DB
3. If so, I want the db to spit an error that says that name and position already exist.

I thought it was going to be easy... by just writing:

```
class Rater < ApplicationRecord

  validate :unique_position, :on => :create, :on => :edit
    
private

  def unique_position
    if Rater.where(name: name, position: position).any?
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

I thought that by returning FALSE, the validate would not allow the action to continue, but I'm able to create duplicates. I've tried searching the net and this site, played around with different methods but not sure I'm using the incorrect keywords for what I'm trying to do.

Appreciative of any direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the validation error in the `errors` object instead of simply returning `false` when the validation fails.

```
class Rater < ApplicationRecord

  validate :validate_name_and_position_uniqueness, on: [:create, :update]
    
  private

  def validate_name_and_position_uniqueness
    return true unless Rater.exists?(name: name, position: position)

    errors.add :base, 'Name and position already taken.'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use uniqueness validation for a column in scope of other column.
Here is the example that can help you.

`validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :position }`

OR

`validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :position }`

*(In case the name field is not mandatory).

If the position is association then user `position_id` the foreign key with the scope.

ex: `{ scope: :position_id }`.

Comment: @ArkEngel just wanted to say that the answer you choose match your exactions, that's fine. Just wanted to say the you can have the custom message this way as well. 
`validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :position, message: "something is not uniq" }`
So this is the way we do in rails.

but if you want to choose custom method for that.
That needs a correction.
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class will be better in that case instead of first `where` and then `exist?`